# GLSL - how to force rendering a fragment?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, pixel

is there any way to force rendering a particuar fragment. As far as I know, fragment shaders are called only for pixels within rasterized triangles. What I need to do is to draw a mark(say a single red pixel) in a constant position on the viewport. I mean something like this:

```
void main(void) {
if(gl_FragCoord.x == vec2(300.5, 300.5)){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
else {
gl_FragColor = getColorFromSampler();
}
```

,while there's no quad nor nothing behind fragment (300.5, 300.5). I don't want to affect performance (no fake background and stuff). How to proceed in such situation?

Comment: That's an application for _Stupid Stencil Buffer Tricks 101_. In other words, clear to red, set your single pixel in the stencil buffer, and make the stencil test fail on equal. Or something different... there's about a dozen equivalent ways. Can do the same with depth, too. Your shader solution obviously works too, but only if you add it to _every_ fragment shader.

Comment: @Damon Well, instead of rendering the whole image red and masking out the pixel with a *"stencil buffer trick"*, why not just render a single red pixel?

Comment: @ChristianRau: Hehehe, of course, that's the obvious solution, but the OP wanted "no quad nor nothing behind the fragment", so I assumed the obvious way doesn't apply  :)  I wonder if `glBlitFrameBuffer` would be allowable...

Comment: @Damon *"nor nothing behind the fragment"* - Oh, I see that's what I missed, sorry. That still seems like an unreasonable request, but it needs to be addressed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything speaking against just rendering a single point on top of the other stuff?

So just render a single `GL_POINTS` primitive at the given pixel. Either use an appropriate orthographic projection to specify the vertex position directly in window space, or just compute the clip space position of the pixel and use an identity vertex transformation. And then all that you need is a simple passthrough fragment shader writing your color of choice.

While you say you want *"nothing behind the fragment"*, I still think that single fragment rendered under the red mark doesn't hurt anyone, at least not more (rather less) than your branch inside the fragment shader just for a single pixel (or any other more elaborate technique using the stencil buffer). If you have any other more strict reason why you cannot render anything else at that position except for the mark, you might want to clarify your problem a bit more.

Comment: What im not sure about this solution is whether GL_POINT actor will be rendered exactly as one pixel and being "pixel perfect" is crucial in my situation. On the other hand combining this with shader solution seems to be an overkill. I'm trying both solutions (this and Damons - unfortunately I'm not too familiar with stencil buffers).

Comment: @WitoldKsiążek Of course it will. This requires you to not mess around with the point size (leave it to 1) and I guess also keep away from multisampling. Then it should be perfectly pixel-perfect, since a point with size 1 is always rendered as a single pixel. But you need to take care of your coordinates and use pixel centers, like (x.5, y.5) (when using an orthographic projection that allows you to specify vertex coordinates in pixel-space), as integer coordinates could cause problems with rounding and make you point "switch over" to the neighbouring pixel...

Comment: @WitoldKsiążek ...But with pixel centers as coordinates, everything should play out nicely without any problems or inaccuracies. Pixel perfect OpenGL does not work right away, but it isn't impossible and doesn't require too much black magic either.

Comment: @WitoldKsiążek Well, *Damon*'s solution requires you to draw a pixel (using a point), too, since that's the only way to modify the stencil buffer. The only thing that his solution buys you is not rendering the fragment behind the red mark, but this doesn't seem worth the effort in your case. Shaders are always needed to render anything (well, except if your using the deprecated fixed-function pipeline, but in this case you don't need any shaders for my solution either, just draw a simple red point).

Comment: I used your solution and it worked fine. Thank you very much.